# Unable to achieve a file operation result in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to match the output of the questions asked below:

Construct a interface where you can look up tweets using username and how many times it was mentioned. Assume @ sign can be placed anywhere, ex mark@, @mark, @mark@john@

I cannot use anything "advance", like .replace() or libs for processing.

[Text file is here](https://files.catbox.moe/6hfje4.txt)

Comment: How are you coming up with those expected numbers?  I count 47 occurrences of `@NASA` in that file, so your code seems to be giving the right answers.

Comment: @jasonharper Did you look at them?

Comment: What are you considering a "mention". "@NASA" or any instance of "NASA"? If the former, then 47 is correct- why are you saying it is not?

Comment: Also, I don't think your code is pasted correctly. Your cleanup() function removes the @ character, and then you are saying "if word in tweet" which will never evaluate to true since "@" is in the variable "word" so the counter will always be 1.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), and include your code in the question itself, with proper formatting. Try to figure out exactly where you are stuck with the problem, and then **ask** a specific question, starting with a question word like "how" or "why" and ending with a question mark (`?`). We do not need hundreds of lines of data to understand the problem - show a few lines, in the question itself, formatted like code. Please also read [mre].

Comment: Removing the code from the question was a mistake, it makes the question nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this returns the values you're expecting but might be worth looking at. I have to leave now so I can't complete my answer right now but I'll come back. This is pretty sloppy but we're confined to not using libraries.

```
def find_username_positions(text: str = None) -> list:
    """"
    Finds all instances of @ character and returns position. Assumes text is being read by line.
    """
    return [pos for pos, char in enumerate(text) if char == '@']


def fetch_all_usernames() -> list:
    """
    Returns list of all usernames.
    :return:
    """
    with open("elon-musk.txt", 'r') as file:
        usernames = []
        for line in file:
            username_positions = find_username_positions(line)
            for username_pos in username_positions:
                username = ''
                pos = username_pos
                while True:
                    username += line[pos]
                    try:
                        if line[pos + 1] in (' ', ':', '\''):  # this assumes if one of these characters occurs, the username has ended
                            usernames.append(username.lower())
                            break
                        pos += 1
                    except IndexError as e:
                        break  # end of file
        return usernames

user = input("Enter username: ").lower()
usernames = fetch_all_usernames()
print(usernames.count(user))
```